# Ho do I call a web service on a database change?

Tags: sql, .net, web-services, database-trigger, sqldependency

There is a business process that happens currently in a totally manual fashion, which seems to me to be a no-brainer to automate. Basically what happens is when a new row is added to a single table in a SQL server, a person then manually makes a change in another business system (based on some very simple business logic).

It's easy to capture the business logic and make the change in the 2nd system programmatically using a web-service. However I don't know how to trigger the calling of the web service when the new row is added into the SQL table.

I've been reading from older forums posts that there are 2 options - the SQL dependency class in .NET and a database trigger in SQL. I was wondering if those are still the 2 main options for a problem like this one.

A colleague of mine showed me the SignalR framework and it was very impressive, but I understand that only works for web applications with a HTML/Javascript front end? I was wondering if there was something similar to that, that's easy to use to simply call a webservice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql dependency and you'll be notified each time your database changes 
I wrote a tutorial a few years back on how to deal with this

[Sql Dependency tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1000315/SQL-Dependency-with-Csharp-NET-and-SQL-Server)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a go.